# Как добавить в тело html нумерацию блоков?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Доброго времени суток. Имеется конструкция вида:

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#id1">Блок</a>
      <meta content="здесь номер Li">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#id2">Блок</a>
      <meta content="здесь номер Li">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#id3">Блок</a>
      <meta content="здесь номер Li">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#id4">Блок</a>
      <meta content="здесь номер Li">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#id5">Блок</a>
      <meta content="здесь номер Li">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Необходимо, подсчитать сколько li классов находится в ul и каждому li классу вывести его порядковый номер в meta который находится внутри. Задать обычным list-style или ::before не подойдет - нужен вывод непосредственно в тело документа для полноценной индексации поисковиками.

Comment: Meta используется только в теге head, в теле документа его использовать нету никакого смысла, и поисковики врятли там его обрабатывают - http://www.wisdomweb.ru/HTML5d/html5_meta.php

Comment: Это для shema разметки Listitem. Meta не виден на странице, но в отличии от ::before читается поисковиками в теле. Поэтому 
необходимо было получить - <meta itemprop="position" content="1">  . На отображение в документе мне все равно, так как необходимо только значение для разметки. В принципе ответ получил , всем спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var liNum = 1;
  $(".block ul li").each(function() {
    $(this).children("meta").attr("content", liNum);
    liNum++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#id1">Блок</a>
      <meta content="здесь номер Li">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#id2">Блок</a>
      <meta content="здесь номер Li">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#id3">Блок</a>
      <meta content="здесь номер Li">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#id4">Блок</a>
      <meta content="здесь номер Li">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#id5">Блок</a>
      <meta content="здесь номер Li">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: И таки что поисковик при индексации выполнит код jq?

Comment: Вообще нужно это для разметки - http://schema.org/ListItem . 
Необязательно в <meta itemprop="position" content="1"> добавлять, возможно и в любой div, ну meta валиден и не виден при отображении.  Я просто не имею понятия будет ли индексироваться подставленное js. Да и нужна ли вообще индексация, может meta разметка и так учитывается?

Answer (score 0):

На серверной стороне считайте и формируйте html. Как-то так (на сервере должен быть установлен php):

```html
<? $i=1; ?>
<div class="block">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#id1">Блок</a>
      <meta content="<? echo($i); $i++; ?>">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#id2">Блок</a>
      <meta content="<? echo($i); $i++; ?>">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#id3">Блок</a>
      <meta content="<? echo($i); $i++; ?>">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#id4">Блок</a>
      <meta content="<? echo($i); $i++; ?>">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#id5">Блок</a>
      <meta content="<? echo($i); $i++; ?>">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```